# Como usar o hook do React useRef com o componente NumberFormat?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks, number-format, react-dom

Eu estou usando a lib `react-number-format` para pegar um valor como moeda formatada em meu form e então salvar ele num estado. Atualmente está dessa forma:

```js
<NumberFormat
      thousandSeparator={true}
      value={form.valor}
      placeholder="R$ ao dia"
      onValueChange={(values) => {
           const { value } = values
           setForm(prev => ({ ...prev, valor: value }))
           }}
      prefix={'R$'}
              />
```

Funciona muito bem, mas eu gostaria de pegar a referência do input com o hook `useRef` do React, porém não sei como faria isso nesse componente específico. Eu tentei isso só que não funcionou:

```js
const inputRef = useRef(null)

<NumberFormat
       ref={inputRef}
       thousandSeparator={true}
       placeholder="R$ ao dia"
       prefix={'R$'}
 />
```

Quando eu logo o `inputRef.current.value` vem undefined. Alguém sabe como pegar a referência dessa máscara?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#getting-reference) do próprio componente, como `ref` é uma propriedade especial do React, você está pegando a referência do componente `NumberFormat`, e não do `input`.

Para pegar a referência do `input`, você pode usar a prop `getInputRef`:

```
<NumberFormat getInputRef={inputRef} />
// <NumberFormat getInputRef={(el) => this.inputElem = el} />
```

A documentação ainda cita que, se você utilizar um input customizado, deve pegar a referência de outra maneira:

```
<NumberFormat inputRef={inputRef} customInput={TextField} />
// <NumberFormat inputRef={(el) => this.inputElem = el} customInput={TextField} />
```

Agora que você tem a referência correta ao input, pode obter o valor :)